# Icon Theme doesn't change in e17

Tags: themes, icons, lxde, enlightenment

I just installed Enlightment (e17) and trying to change the icon theme doesn't seem to do anything, i also have LXDE installed and i'm trying to change the icons from the LXAppeareance application but it doesn't do anything.

How can i make e17 use the icons i want?, it keeps using the GNOME defualt icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Main Menu > Settings > Settings Panel > Look > Icon Theme`. You will need to override the general theme I guess

[image]

[image]